# Using Accumulo's iterators and combiners to aggregate values from multiple rows

Tags: mapreduce, accumulo

I wanted to know if it is possible to perform aggregation operations on values stored in multiple rows. For example, I have the following table

```
rowID   colFam   colQual   value
00000   0000     A         12
00000   0001     B         Test
00001   0000     A         35
00001   0001     B         Foo
00002   0000     A         7
00002   0001     B         Bar
```

What I am trying to do is find the average of all values stored with columnQualifier A. Is it possible using Accumulo's Iterators, Filters or Combiners?

I saw the StatsCombiner, but that combiner performs aggregation on different versions (rowID, colFam and colQual is the same but timestamp is different) of the same key instead of performing aggregation on distinct keys itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combiners (and their predecessors, Aggregators), do aggregation for the same key. You can create an iterator which transforms multiple keys into a single key, but you'll still have to aggregate in the client, because you'll have a bunch of partial computations being produced for each tablet.

You could use [Apache Fluo](https://fluo.apache.org)'s "observers" to keep aggregate your stats while you ingest to your table.

There's probably multiple solutions. I would suggest taking a look at Apache Fluo, and if you really don't want to use that, then consider aggregating partial sums/counts as an iterator in each tablet, and doing the final aggregation on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this with the fact that I haven't used Accumulo in years, but I'm not sure that you'll be able to do that completely on the server side.  The reason being, that you're looking for values in the CQ which are going to be spread out amungst all of the nodes of the Accumulo cluster.  I.e. the tablet server that knows about 00000:0000 isn't (guaranteed) to know anything about values for 00002:0000, etc.  You're probably either going to need to do a second indexing of your data to provide this functionality (i.e. making the CQ the RowID), or you'll have to do the aggrigation on the client side.   You might be able to do a hybrid approach of doing some agg per tablet and doing the remaining agg on the client side.